# How do I read this Swift syntax?

Tags: swift, vapor

I am using [Vapor](https://vapor.github.io/documentation/getting-started/hello-world.html) and one of the first thing is to use get method which looks like following:

```
drop.get("hello") { request in
    return "Hello, world!"
}
```

Now my understanding was that the closures are like variable of type functions. Correct? Here I see we call a method `get` on an instance of `Droplet` class called drop and pass in a string.

What is with the closure being called/passed inside the get method body? How do I read this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called *trailing closure syntax*.  If the last parameter of a function is a closure, it can be placed in curly braces immediately following a closing parenthesis around the previous parameters.

The `get` method here takes two parameters: a `String` and a closure with some signature like `(Request) -> ()`

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102

You'll also see cases where the *only* parameter is a closure, like the `map()` method on an array. In these situations, the parentheses can be omitted entirely and the closure is written in curly braces immediately following the function name, e.g.:

```
let lowerCasedWords = arrayOfWords.map{ $0.lowercased() }
```